# Best Practices - Sending clients large documents in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating a large chat application, and my colleague told me I should switch the way I handle sending the client data.

I am using MongoDB, I have multiple schemas however the the one of concern is the live-chat one.

```
{
    name: String,
    members: Number,
    chatMessages: [{
         message: String,
         date: Number,
         userProfileImage: Number,
         isMod: Boolean
    }],

}
```

This works nice when the chat room is small, however I realized I was sending huge documents at full to the client such as

```
{
    name: "Chat Room Name",
    members: 123,
    chatMessages: [{
         message: "Example Message",
         date: 1500075913,
         userProfileImage: 352356263,
         isMod: false
    } ... 1000's of times
    ],
}
```

And I knew there had to be a more efficient way, every single user was getting this giant document, yet almost 90% of them only needed the last 50 documents. So after a while of brainstorming I came up with 3 possible solutions, and I am not sure which one I should implement.

1. Just send the client the last 50 chat messages, and use web sockets on the client's html page to signal when they scrolled up far enough to need a new set of 50 messages. I was not sure how much better this would of been as I am still finding the document, and storing all the data within a huge array of object.
2. Create a new schema for the messages, and story an array of message ids, (instead of 1000's objects, 1000's of _id's). However I wasn't sure if this was any more efficient as now MongoDB will have to search through all the messages ever made and then repopulate them.
3. This was the most creative one I can think of, create a schema that stores 50 messages, and in the live-chat schema only have the id references to the 50 message schema, and server the client the last one, followed up by additional requests made by the client via web sockets.

So those were my attempts, I was wondering how I should change up my database logic so I can be as efficient and optimized as possible. Thanks.

In case this helps, here is some data:

- Chat rooms in database: 1,425
- Largest room: 17,000 messages
- Top 10% of chat rooms average: 800 messages
- Bottom 50% of chat rooms average: 35 messages

Comment: The first solution is the simplest, and probably the most performant.

Comment: I forgot to mention, and now updated my initial post, but users can update and delete any message posted. With this new case is it still the most effective to use the first solution? For example, say a user updated message #245, the entire collection will need to get updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would revamp all the logic, and change strategy for:

- each chat room is a collection
- each message is a document with a unique incremental ID and timestamp

You can use [`findAndModify()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) to store the messages in order and guarantee that IDs will not duplicate.

MongoDB is far better at storing millions of small documents than large documents:

> The biggest hit on performance I have seen is when documents grow,
>   particularly when you are doing huge numbers of updates. If the
>   document size increases after it has been written then the entire
>   document has to be read and rewritten to another part of the data file
>   with the indexes updated to point to the new location, which takes
>   significantly more time than simply updating the existing document.

[Processing 2 Billion Documents A Day And 30TB A Month With MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/processing-2-billion-documents-a-day-and-30tb-a)

Then retrieving the last 50 documents is a trivial task: the range of documents is `[current ID, current ID - 50]`. With an index, it will be pretty fast to run with.

Garbage collection can be made to delete all messages below a certain ID (example: history of 25000 messages and no more => delete all documents with ID < max ID - 25000).

Eventually you can also resort to [MongoDB's capped collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) : they allow ordered writes and collection consumption in a streaming fashion (event based).

Comment: I forgot to mention this in my initial post, but users can modify any message they posted to the chat room. I now understand that updating huge documents is a big no, and I should use smaller documents so my question is now should I make the single chat room a collection of individual message collections, 50 sized message collections?

Comment: Modifying a message or single document is ok (though it excludes the capped collections solution). Storing multiple messages into one single document is messy.

Comment: Also a quick performance question, I still have trouble comprehending how populating so many ID's can be so efficient. I may be wrong but doesn't MongoDB have to manually find each document's ID, from every other documents ID, and as more users and more rooms pop up, would make this process even slower?

Comment: When you index your IDs MongoDB has no issues in crawling millions because indexes are stored *entirely* in memory, in order (ASC, DESC, etc.), and are thus easy to browse for any range based queries.